# Image used by another process

Tags: c#, image, bitmap

I am getting a screenshot of the computer, then setting it as a picture box by copying it and then using it but after the first time it does it, it says the picture is being used by another process but im guessing i just dungoofed.

```
               public void UpdatePic()
    {
        String newtemp = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyPictures) + "\\screentemp.png";
        if (File.Exists(newtemp)) { File.Delete(newtemp); }
        File.Copy(screendirect, newtemp);
        Image image = Image.FromFile(newtemp);
        try
        {
            using (Bitmap tempBitmap = new Bitmap(image))
            {
                Size size = new Size(pictureBox1.Width, pictureBox1.Height);
                Bitmap backgroundBitmap = new Bitmap(size.Width, size.Height);
                using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(backgroundBitmap))
                {
                    g.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
                    // Get the set of points that determine our rectangle for resizing.
                    Point[] corners = { new Point(0, 0), new Point(backgroundBitmap.Width, 0), new Point(0, backgroundBitmap.Height)};
                    g.DrawImage(tempBitmap, corners);
                    g.Dispose();
                }
                pictureBox1.Image = backgroundBitmap;

            }
        }
        finally
        {

        }
    }
```

Comment: Why does your `ScreenShareTmr_Tick` method not use using statements for the `Bitmap` and `Graphics` creation like the `UpdatePic` method does? That'll be your issue

Comment: Note that `Image` implements `IDisposable`. Since this image comes from a file, it possibly has a reference/handle to the file as well. This may cause your 'file in use' issue. Dispose handles to files as soon as you're not using them anymore. Also, `Bitmap bmp` is not disposed.

Comment: So could you show me which i have to dispose of in the answer?

Comment: I see you revised your code. The only object left to dispose is `image`. Note that there is also an overload `new Bitmap(string)`.

Comment: Fixed it up, pretty easy. just put brackets using(image)

Comment: please post the answer as i m having a similar issue..